# presence_of_all_elements_located returns partial result

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Below is my code. I try to retrieve the comment owner's thumbnail. But I do not get link of the complete set. Few links values are shown as None. XPath point to correct location ,but unable to retrieve the value.

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import json
import mysql.connector as conn

import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "eager"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DRIVER_PATH = <your driver path>

    wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH , desired_capabilities=caps, options=options)

    url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8DkCAN1z-3U"

    wd.get(url)
    wd.maximize_window()
    wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 20)
    last_height = wd.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
    while True:
        # Scroll down to bottom
        wd.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0]);", last_height)
        # Wait to load page
        time.sleep(1)

        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = wd.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height

    time.sleep(5)
    comm_thumbNail = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,
                                                                     '//*[@id="contents"]/ytd-comment-thread-renderer//*[@id="author-thumbnail"]//*[@id="img"]')))
    i = 1
    for comm_img in comm_thumbNail:
        print(f"Comment {i}")
        print(comm_img.get_attribute("src"))
        i += 1
```

Please find the Element details which I have used to capture the thumbnail:

```
<div id="body" class="style-scope ytd-comment-renderer">
  <div id="author-thumbnail" class="style-scope ytd-comment-renderer">
    <a class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-comment-renderer" href="/channel/UCbKW-xojG16_Es1emwZ12TA">
      <yt-img-shadow fit="" height="40" width="40" class="style-scope ytd-comment-renderer no-transition" style="background-color: transparent;" loaded=""><!--css-build:shady--><img id="img" draggable="false" class="style-scope yt-img-shadow" alt="Sara Tariq" height="40" width="40" src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AMLnZu_DDgbhvK5MtV0hgEpm8UnjVtk6I1ykjc-mV5TK=s88-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj"></yt-img-shadow>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Could anyone please help me to understand what I am missing here ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `get_attribute("src")` looks for but to get a link you should use `get_attribute("href")`. Also if nothing else works, use BeautifulSoup to parse the links.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all("tag", attrs={"type": "element"})
```

udpated

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
text = soup.find_all("a", attrs={"class": "yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-comment-renderer"})
```

Comment: I have updated my question with details of elements also. If you see the image link, it is placed at src. I didnt find any attribute for href to extract the image

Comment: Try the updated version. You still have to parse it from `text` though